# woocommerce dynamic pricing variations

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I have a product with the following attribues:

- Color: Red, Blue, Green, Yellow
- Size: S, M, L, XL
- Type: New, Old

---

This is the pricing system:

- Base price: $2,50
- Color Red = price + $5,00
- Color Blue = price = $3,50
- Size S = price + $3,00

---

Woocommerce does not support this system. In Woocommerce I have to give every posible combination(*variation*) a specific price.

Is there any plugin free or paid te help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that woocommerce have any free plugin for kind of functionality. You have to do lot of customizations in woocommerce variations and you have to master in woocommerce to do so.

One thing can help you for this feature is Magento! Try magento , it is different platform but will provide this feature. It has a inbuilt facility for this combinations of product.